# In Angular2 mailto link is recognized as component route

Tags: angular, mailto

I am trying to create a mailto link in an Angular project. But instead of opening outlook. Angular picks it up as a component route. How do I fix this?

When i try the following code:

```html
<a [href]="mailto:myName@myDomain.com">myName@myDomain.com</a>
```

When I click the link I get routed to an undefined page. And get the following error message:

````
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'null'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2469)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2450)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:34)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html should look like this:

```html
<a href="mailto:myName@myDomain.com">myName@myDomain.com</a>
```

Note it doesn't have the `[]` around the `href` attribute. When you wrap an attribute in `[]` its expecting a variable.

If for some reason, you still want to use the binding, you could pass the value as a string:

```html
<a [href]="'mailto:myName@myDomain.com'">myName@myDomain.com</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`[href]="mailto:myName@myDomain.com"`

This syntax `<[]>` is for data binding, so angular try to resolve `"mailto:myName@myDomain.com"` as variable. You should try like below

```html
<a href="mailto:myName@myDomain.com">myName@myDomain.com</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the awnser. Both solutions work. So I selected the fist awnser comming in as the solution.